# Dynamically loading usercontrol in updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel

So I'm trying to dynamically load a usercontrol into a placeholder in another usercontrol inside a updatepanel.

basically I've got this markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPopup" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <UC:Popup runat="server" ID="UC_Popup" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And then this markup inside that usercontrol (Popup):

```
<div id="modal">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phPopupPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:Label ID="lblModal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

In the codebehind of the popup usercontrol I have:

```
public void Show(UserControl control) {
    this.phPopupPlaceholder.Controls.Add(control);
    this.lblModal.Text = "Loaded";
}
```

And I call this show method elsewhere with:

```
Popup.show(new MyUserControl());
```

Nothing loads into the placeholder though.

But in the show method I can load regular server-controls fine like this:

```
this.phPopupPlaceholder.Controls.Add(new Label(){ Text = "Label!" });
```

Can anyone explain to me why regular controls are loaded fine, but my usercontrol isn't loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I learned that I HAVE to use LoadControl method apparently, but I don't quite understand why this is necessary :/